# Inline styling in canvas with node.js skia-canvas

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, inline-styles, bold

I am trying to make some words bold from the text using skia-canvas or any canvas node package.
Currently, I can make the canvas like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsx51.jpg)

But I want to make **some of the words bold** like [this](https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/982270625806696449/983013218513453096/unknown.png)

Currently I am doing

```js
const drawTweetQuoteCanvas = async (width, height, { text, name, username, pfp, followers, followings, fontArr, returnFormat, returnType, returnQuality }) => {
  //const height = 500;

  let canvas = new Canvas(width, height);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  //font size etup according to text length // max text is 280 so... no worries
  let fontSize;
  if (text.length <= 60) fontSize = 60;
  else if (text.length > 60 && text.length <= 100) fontSize = 50;
  else if (text.length > 100 && text.length <= 150) fontSize = 39;
  else if (text.length > 150 && text.length <= 180) fontSize = 35;
  else if (text.length > 180 && text.length <= 210) fontSize = 32;
  else if (text.length > 210 && text.length <= 250) fontSize = 30;
  else if (text.length > 250 && text.length <= 295) fontSize = 29;
  else if (text.length > 295 && text.length <= 310) fontSize = 28;
  else fontSize = 26;

  //Loading fonts
  if (fontArr && fontArr.length) FontLibrary.use("Baloobhaijaan", fontArr);

    // Black background
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, height);
  
  //text styles
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
  ctx.font = `${fontSize}px Baloobhaijaan`;
  ctx.textWrap = true;
  ctx.textAlign = "center";

  //text measures
  let tm = ctx.measureText(text, width - height);
  // console.log(tm.lines.length, tm.lines);
  let txtH = tm.lines.length > 1 ? (tm.lines[1].baseline - tm.lines[0].baseline) * tm.lines.length : tm.lines[0].height;
  let exH = 20;
  let txtY = (height / 2) - (txtH / 2) - exH;
  // console.log({
  //   lines: tm.lines.length,
  //   txtY,
  //   calcTxtY: (height / 2) - (txtH / 2)
  // })
  let nameY = txtY + txtH + 50;
  let usernameY = nameY + 50;
  let followY = usernameY + 50;

  // var text = "Hello! How are you?";

  try {
    let langsArr = await detectlanguage.detect(text);
    // console.log(textLangRes)
    // return;
    // let langsArr = await textLangRes.json();
    let lang = langsArr[0].language;
    console.log('arr: ',langsArr)
    console.log('lang: ',lang)
    if(langsArr.length == 1 && lang == "ar"){
      ctx.direction = 'rtl';
    }else{
      ctx.direction = 'ltr';
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }


  // texts
  ctx.fillText(text, (height + width) / 2 - 50, txtY, width - height);
  // console.log(text.length, fontSize);
  // ctx.fillStyle = "red";
  ctx.direction = 'ltr';
  ctx.font = "bold 47px Baloobhaijaan";
  ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffffe2"
  ctx.fillText(name, (height + width) / 2 - 50, nameY, width - height)
  ctx.font = "italic 38px Baloobhaijaan";
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray"
  ctx.fillText(`@${username}`, (height + width) / 2 - 50, usernameY, width - height);
  ctx.font = "28px Baloobhaijaan";
  ctx.fillText(`${followers} followers   ${followings} following`, (height + width) / 2 - 50, followY, width - height)

  // username
  // ctx.fillText(username, height / 2, height / 2 - 50);


  let pfpwidth = height - 70;
  // shade
  const shade = ctx.createRadialGradient(-200, height / 2 - 60, pfpwidth + 100, -800, height / 2, pfpwidth + 800);
  // shade.addColorStop(0, "pink");
  // shade.addColorStop(0.8, "white");
  // shade.addColorStop(1, "red");
  shade.addColorStop(0, "#00000000");
  // shade.addColorStop(0.01, "#0000001a");
  // shade.addColorStop(0.1, "#0000001f");
  shade.addColorStop(1, "#000000");


  // draw pfp
  ctx.filter = "grayscale(100%)";
  if (pfp) {
    let img = await loadImage(pfp);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, pfpwidth, height);
  }

  ctx.fillStyle = shade;
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, pfpwidth, height);



  // watermark shade
  let waterMarkH = 60;
  const watermarkShade = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, height - (waterMarkH / 2), height, height - (waterMarkH / 2));
  watermarkShade.addColorStop(0, "#000000");
  watermarkShade.addColorStop(0.7, "#00000000");

  ctx.fillStyle = watermarkShade;
  ctx.fillRect(0, height - waterMarkH, height, waterMarkH);

  //watermark
  ctx.font = "italic 38px Baloobhaijaan";
  ctx.fillStyle = "gray"
  ctx.textAlign = "start";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.fillText(`Created by @${config.username}`, 20, height - (waterMarkH / 2));



  if (returnFormat === 'dataURL') {
    return canvas.toDataURL(returnType ? returnType : 'image/jpeg', returnQuality ? returnQuality : 1);
  } else if (returnFormat === 'buffer') {
    return canvas.toBuffer(returnType ? returnType : 'image/jpeg', returnQuality ? returnQuality : 1);
  } else {
    return canvas;
  }
}


let tweetQuote = await drawTweetQuoteCanvas(1200, 630, {
  // text: 'Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet a.',
  text: `Lorem ipsum dolor, sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab accusantium nobis odit impedit nostrum distinctio adipisci? Aliquid perspiciatis dolor inventore!`,
  name: "Prasant kumar",
  username: 'prasant123whatevern2',
  pfp: 'https://cdn.discordapp.com/avatars/800445583046213663/027359d038895040a33236d17596d98f.png?size=4096',
  followers: "-2.3 M",
  followings: "+254",
  fontArr: [path.join(__dirname, './assets/fonts/Baloo_Bhaijaan_2/BalooBhaijaan2-VariableFont_wght.ttf')],
  returnFormat: 'buffer',
  returnType: 'image/jpeg',
  returnQuality: 1
});
fs.writeFileSync('./abcd.jpeg', tweetQuote)
```

I tried measuring the text width and draw in chunk, but that didn't work for multiline as I'm using `ctx.textWrap = true` and that didn't align in center when I used `ctx.textAlign = "center"`.

Is there any built in method to add inline style to canvas text ? or any node packge or any workaround ?

I found some solutions for this, but those are for single line only.

Comment: Your snippet does not work...

Comment: This code is for node-js so it won't work on browser.
I found a solution btw.
Had to draw word by word. Didn't find any built in method or node package to draw multiline centered text.